# Foundation 5 grid: text flowing beside 2 blocks stacked on the right

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm new to Foundation and there's something I haven't managed to achieve using the grid: on medium and large displays, I want to have an 8-col article flowing beside 2 blocks stacked on the right: a 7-col `figure` on top of a 4-col `aside` container. (On small displays, the three blocks will simply be stacked).

[image: Page layout]

Going from this basic snippet:

```
    <div class="row">
        <figure class="medium-7 columns right"></figure>
        <section class="medium-8 columns"></section>
        <aside class="medium-4 columns right"></figure>
    </div>
```

I've tried all kinds of variants with the grid classes (right, push, pull, offset...), but can't get it to work as I want.

The difficult thing here is to get the text to wrap around the figure. I wonder if Foundation 5's grid system can do this sort of thing. Any idea?

(PS: what exactly is the `.columns` class supposed to do, as opposed to not using it?)

Comment: This is not how any typical row/column grid system works.  You'll have to put this all inside a single column and use floats for the `aside` and `figure`.

Comment: OK, thanks, that's what I thought. I'll have to make it responsive somehow...